# Get list of nodes in pastry overlay

Tags: network-programming, dht

Please, how can i get the list of nodes in pastry overlay ? is that possible ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe its straight forward to get a list of all the nodes in a pastry overlay. Not all nodes are aware of every node in the overlay. However they do know about the nodes in their leafset. The leafset can be found using : node.getLeafSet()

I've done queit a bit of reading on pastry and generally there doesn't seem to be a need to check all the nodes in a network. If you want to see this for testing purposes i.e that a node has enetered the overlay successfully, just use the .getLeafSet()